# Why does my Github Action fail when trying to build an IPA (Not using fastlane)

Tags: ios, github-actions, ipa

I am trying to use GitHub Actions for CI/CD, when trying to create the IPA file I get a failure when trying to find the provisioning profile.

I have the files stored in the secrets section of Github, and they appear to load properly.

```
  env:
    BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ***
    P12_PASSWORD: ***
    BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ***
    KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ***
1 identity imported.
```

I created a ExportOptions.plist file and tried printing that out to ensure GitHub was reading it properly.

```
    {
  "method" => "ad-hoc"
  "provisioningProfiles" => {
    "com.strykeout.Demo_CICD" => "PROFILE UUID"
  }

  "signingCertificate" => "iPhone Distribution: Nathan (XXXXXXX)"

  "signingStyle" => "manual"
  "teamID" => "XXXXXXXX"

}

2022-01-31 22:55:17.741 xcodebuild[1633:7990] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging _createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path "/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/Demo_CICD_2022-01-31_22-55-17.740.xcdistributionlogs".

error: exportArchive: "Demo_CICD.app" requires a provisioning profile.

** EXPORT FAILED **
Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""Demo_CICD.app" requires a provisioning profile." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="Demo_CICD.app" requires a provisioning profile., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}
```

It seems like it can't find the provisioningProfiles section of the export options, but it's clearly there.

This is the full workflow:

```
name: Archive Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Archive File on merge to Main 
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile
        env:
          BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}
          P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
          BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 }}
          KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}  
        run: |
          # create variables
          CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
          PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
          KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db
          # import certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
          echo -n "$BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output $CERTIFICATE_PATH
          echo -n "$BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output $PP_PATH
          # create temporary keychain
          security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          # import certificate to keychain
          security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          # apply provisioning profile
          mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
          cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
      - name: Build archive
        env:
          scheme: ${{ 'Demo_CICD' }}
        run: |
            xcodebuild \
            -configuration Release \
            -scheme $scheme \
            -archivePath ./demo/Demo_CICD.xcarchive \
            archive 
      - name: Build IPA
        run: |
            plutil -p exportOptions.plist
            xcodebuild \
            -configuration Release \
            -exportArchive \
            -archivePath ./demo/Demo_CICD.xcarchive \
            -exportPath /demo/demoIPA.ipa \
            -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

Comment: Are you following [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development)? I didn't understand where you're using the `env.BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the env.BUILD_PP is directly from that documentation. It is a local secret file stored in the repository (and then referenced in the env section of the script) more details on how I did that are here https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development

Comment: Could you update the question with the full workflow step that will add the certificate and apply the provisioning profile, as shown in the documentation? To check how you did it?

Comment: I have updated the question with the full workflow that is failing. Please let me know if there is more detail I can provide (I appreciate the assistance)

Comment: Well I feel dumb... apparently Xcode was updating my app bundle ID from demo_cicd to demo-cicd (underscore was changed to hypen) and thus didnt match the exportOptions Plist Its working now.

Comment: Great, thank you for sharing the answer :)

Comment: hey @Nathan did you create the exportOption plist on the fly from a step in GitHub actions or you have checked in that from the code ? My build seem to use the development profile instead of the App Store profile that was installed using the same method as documented. I am wondering if that will be solve when I provide the method in the export options plist. If so how to handle the sensitive info in it .Thinking of making the plist file too a base64 string. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was:

apparently Xcode was updating my app bundle ID from demo_cicd to demo-cicd (underscore was changed to hyphen) and thus didn't match the exportOptions Plist Its working now.